# Condition after for loop (Batch/CMD)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

So I currently have this batch that converts every .MTS on the current folder to .MP4 using ffmpeg, however when it is done I get both .mp4 and .mts on the folder.
I have 2 batches, one to convert the files and another one to delete the unwanted files afterwards, but I'm having trouble trying to join them in the same batch script.

Converter.bat:

`for %%i in (*.MTS) do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 256k "%%~ni.mp4"`

Delete.bat:

`del /S *.MTS`

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

to "join them in a batch script", just write them into the same batch script:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.MTS) do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 256k "%%~ni.mp4"
del /S *.MTS
```

Although I would recommend:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.MTS) do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 256k "%%~ni.mp4" && del /S "%%i"
```

`&&` means "do the following only if the previous was successful", so the file will only be deleted, when the conversion was successful.

(reconsider `del /s` - it will delete the file in the current folder and all subfolders. A simple `del "%%i"` will only delete the processed file and keep files in any subfolders)

Comment: `&&` is exactly what I was looking forward, Thank you!

Comment: for future use:  the opposite is `||` ("if previous command failed then"). You can even combine them: `<command> && echo succesfull || echo failed`